# VueJS: How to prevent textarea default behavior

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to implement a slack like feature to send a message only when pressing exact enter (without shift pressed)

Considering this vue template

`<textarea type="text" v-model="message" @keyup.enter.exact="sendMessage($event)"></textarea>`

 with this component

```
export default {
  name: 'Typing',
  data() {
      return {
          message: null
      }
  },
  methods: {
      sendMessage(e) {
        // e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() have no impact
        this.$socket.emit('message', { text: this.message });
        console.log(this.message); // Print the message with another '\n' at the end due to textarea default behavior
      }
  }
}
```

Does anyone has an idea of how I can avoid having the last '\n' without using a regex to delete it before sending it to the backend (which I think will be dirty) ?

Thank you

PS : I'm pretty new to VueJS stack and hope that my question is not obvious

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680638/preventing-new-line-in-) is similar but the proposed solution is not working

Comment: IMO keyup event is inappropriate for this purpose. Keypress, keydown and keyup have side effects, like your '\n' character. When I finish my coffee, I will write an example to answer.

Comment: Looks like duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680638/preventing-new-line-in-textarea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing new line in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680638/preventing-new-line-in-textarea)

Answer (score 57):

## Problem

```
<textarea
  type="text"
  v-model="message"
  @keyup.enter.exact="sendMessage($event)"
>
</textarea>
```

The code calls the `sendMessage` method on the `keyup` event of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. The `keyup` event is fired **after** the key has been released. Therefore the code is calling the method after the key has been pressed, after the default behaviour of the key run (entering a newline) and after the key has been released. `preventDefault` will not prevent the problem as the behaviour trying to be prevented has already occurred, before the `keyup` event.

## Solution

As we have identified the following:

- We wish to prevent the default behaviour of pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
- The `keyup` event is fired after the default behaviour has already occurred.

The solution is to prevent the default behaviour on the `keydown` event and call the method on the `keyup` event.

> **Note**: it is important to only call the method on the `keyup` event to avoid multiple calls if the user holds down the key.

```
  <textarea
    v-model="value"
    @keydown.enter.exact.prevent
    @keyup.enter.exact="send"
    @keydown.enter.shift.exact="newline"
  >
  </textarea>
```

A method which appends a newline to the textarea value can be called when the <kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> combination is pressed.

Below is a snippet demonstrating all the behaviours described in the solution.

```js
new Vue({
  template: `
    <div>
      <textarea
        v-model="value"
        @keydown.enter.exact.prevent
        @keyup.enter.exact="send"
        @keydown.enter.shift.exact="newline"
      >
      </textarea>
    </div>
  `,
  
  data: {
    value: '',
  },
  
  methods: {
    newline() {
      this.value = `${this.value}\n`;
    },

    send() {
      console.log('========');
      console.log(this.value);
      console.log('========');
    },
  },
}).$mount('#root');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## Further reading

- [W3C Specification for Keyboard Events](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboardevents)
- Specifically [event order](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboard-event-order) and [event types](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#events-keyboard-types)

Comment: Note, if you are doing this on a component rather than the native textarea element then it's `@keydown.native.enter.exact.prevent`

Comment: Works fine even without using `native` modifier in Quasar framework.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem have solution simple like that:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: ''
  },
  methods: {
    sendMessage () {   
      console.log(this.message, this.message.length)
      // this.$socket.emit('message', {text: this.message});
      // clear textarea: this.message = ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-model="message" @keydown.enter.exact.prevent="sendMessage"></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Vue built-in `prevent`

```
<textarea type="text" v-model="message" @keyup.enter.exact.prevent="sendMessage($event)"></textarea>
```